# how to create a new array using angular JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

```
<html ng-app="">
<body ng-controller="controller">
    <button class="btn"  ng-click="create('new') >Click</button>
</body>
</html>

<script>
function controller($scope) {
    $scope.create = function(id) {
        // What will be the code to create a new array 
        // having name contained in variable?
    };
}
<script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create an object property with the name stored in variable you should use bracket notation. In your case:

```
function controller($scope) {
    $scope.create = function(id) {
        $scope[id] = [];
        // do something with new array
    };
}
```